# Place logo inside footline zone in a beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, positioning

In this code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\logo{\raisebox{-2cm}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}}}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd = 1.0\paperwidth, ht = 2.25ex, dp = 1ex, center]{author in head/foot}
    This is footline
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
  Frame Contents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I try to use a negative value with `\raisebox` to force the logo inside the footline zone.

The result is

[image]

My attempt to place the logo inside the footline zone has been unsuccessful. How to hack (apart from inserting the logo directly into footline)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What about a tikz overlay?

**Edit: fixed to "work" for every frame:**

**Last edit: `mshow` variable has to be 1 for logo to appear or another integer to not appear**

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
%\logo{\raisebox{-2cm}{\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}}}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd = 1.0\paperwidth, ht = 2.25ex, dp = 1ex, center]{author in head/foot}
    This is footline
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}

\xdef\mshow{0}
\def\showlogo{\ifnum\mshow=1 \begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
    \node at ([yshift=0.2cm,xshift=-0.25cm]current page.south east){\includegraphics[width=0.5cm]{example-image-a}};
    \end{tikzpicture}\fi}
\let\oldbeginframe\frame
\renewenvironment{frame}[1][ ]{\oldbeginframe{#1}\bgroup\showlogo}{\egroup}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
  Frame Contents

\end{frame}

\xdef\mshow{1}
\begin{frame}{Title2}
  Frame 2

\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Title3}
  Frame 3

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That calls for inserting the `tikz` overlay in every frame?

Comment: I think we can fix it for this... just give me a minute

Comment: @Viesturs... fixed to work for every frame... (Just don't forget to double compile)

Comment: Nice! Another challenge - the logo should not appear on the titlepage. :)

Comment: @Viesturs Another chalenge (7 euros :P) [fixed... just cahnge mshow variable to 1 for logo to be shown or another integer to hide it whenever you want]

Answer (score 2):

If you do not care about the footline symbols and do not modify (for whatever reason the footline), there is a dirty solution (which I cannot recommend).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{eso-pic}
\AddToShipoutPictureFG{% Add picture to background of every page
  \AtPageLowerLeft{\hspace*{\paperwidth}\hspace*{-1cm}\includegraphics[width=1cm]{example-image-a}
}}

\setbeamertemplate{footline}{
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd = 1.0\paperwidth, ht = 2.25ex, dp = 1ex, center]{author in head/foot}
    This is footline
  \end{beamercolorbox}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{Title}
  Frame Contents
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: What if I don't need the logo on the titlepage?

Comment: @Viesturs Just move the command `\AddToShipoutPictureFG` to the second slide. For further details, please see the `eso-pic` docu.